# Change PouchDB directory in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, pouchdb

I would like change PouchDB directory in my Electron App. When i update my APP (re-install), all my data are destroyed.

So, i would like change my PouchDB directory for no remove my data when i re-install my App.

My code :

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
const Presentation = new PouchDB('~/test/db');
```

This return an error :

> err {type: "OpenError", name: "OpenError", cause: Error: IO error:
>   ~/test/db/LOCK: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type, message: "IO
>   error: ~/test/db/LOCK: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type", stack:
>   "OpenError: IO error: ~/test/db/LOCK: Aucun
>   fichier…es/abstract-leveldown/abstract-leveldown.js:39:16"}

Anyone know how i can change my directory or just not remove my data when i re-install my Electron App ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~ is a Bash feature called "tilde expansion". It's a function of the shell, electron can't process it. Use new PouchDB('./test/db') record instead.

You can use [pouchdb-dump-cli](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-dump-cli) package to export database dump and then import it using [pouchdb-load](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-load) package.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. For dump-cli, i can exec the command from javascrilt file in Electron App ?

Comment: [pouchdb-replication-stream](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-replication-stream) fits better for using in application source code.
dump-cli is used as terminal command

Answer (score 1):

The IO error is happening because pouch db cannot create the folder in the specified location. Electron apps usually need to store configs, local db files in the appData + appName location. This location has full access to the app.

```js
const appName='<Electron App Name>'
const db = new PouchDB(
    path.join(app.getPath('appData'), appName, "db")
  );
```

Ref:

- https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname
- https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store